# Corrective underline in CSS input?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, input

(might be a duplicate, the wording is hard to refine)

I noticed that Chrome sometimes implements the grammar/spelling corrective-dashed-red underline in input boxes.

Is there a way to get rid of this function, either through css or js, at least in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the attribute `spellcheck` for HTML elements might be what you are looking for:

```
<textarea spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Should work on every element type, especially inputs. Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck